# what's the meaning of this sentence? why is the butler on all fours

Tags: spoken-english

I was watching Growing pains TV shows, one scene is that Carol is watching a show called "the sturgeons of Pitt Street", and her mom was watching too and asked Carol "why is the butler on all fours? " then Carol answered the family dog died, and they didn't have the heart to tell their grandma.

I don't understand why Carol's mother ask "why is the butler on all fours? " and the meaning of it. Anyone could help? Thanks.

Ref: it is from Growing pains TV shows, first season，5th episode."super dad".[image]

Answer (score 1):

"All fours" is a term that means he was on his hands and knees like an animal.

Comment: Well, more specifically I guess the butler was *pretending* to be the dog, so the (presumably senile) grandmother wouldn't be upset that the dog was missing.  This sort of thing only really works in television sitcoms, of course.

Comment: Yes. I assumed having the knowledge that he was on his hands and knees then the rest of the scenario would be obvious but I should have clarified just in case.